# What time it takes for Sentinel-2 images to be uploaded from source hub to Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

Is it possible to calculate a time it takes for Sentinel-2 image (i.e L1C) to be uploaded from source hub to Earth Engine servers? I guess `'system:time_start'` is not an ingestion time but rather an image acquisition time

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anyway to get access to the ingestion time. The time to ingestion seems to vary a lot. You can play around with a script like this to get a feel for how long it takes for your area. Tweak the `timeDelta`/`timeUnit`.

```
var timeDelta = 3
var timeUnit = 'days'

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(Map.getBounds(true))

var now = ee.Date(new Date())  
var nowCount = collection
  .filterDate(now.advance(-timeDelta, timeUnit), now)
  .size()

var monthAgo = now.advance(-1, 'month')
var monthAgoCount = collection
  .filterDate(monthAgo.advance(-timeDelta, timeUnit), monthAgo)
  .size()

print('Within ' + timeDelta + ' ' + timeUnit  + ' from now:', nowCount)
print('Within ' + timeDelta + ' ' + timeUnit  + ' from a month ago:', monthAgoCount)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e088011f0a68b2d6a60a0c139e2d4f2